# How to do a summation calculation for a referral program in ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

For an e-commerce application, I have an order table for and a referral table which belongs to each completed order. Once an order is completed, its `order_id` is stored in the `referral` table.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord 
    belongs_to :product 
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
    has_one :referral
```

For each order, if it is a referred purchase, it will have a `referral_id` in the `order` table which belongs to another users order(the person who sent the referral). If it wasn't a referred purchase, the `referral_id` will be null.

There are certain reward milestones for the referrals, for example 1 referral is $5 and 3 referrals are $20...

So if a user has made 3 orders which has generated referral_id:1, referral_id:2, and referral_id:3, how do I go into the order table and count number of referrals for that user per referral_id(1,2 and 3) and then calculate what their rewards are for each one and sum up the three. So if referral_id:1 had 1 referral and referral_id:2 and referral_id:3 had 3 referrals it would be 5+20+20=45 in rewards.

And is it best to store that number in a table?

I want to do this with the lowest performance/speed penalty on the app.

Hope this question finds you well, I'm new to RoR :)

Comment: if referral_id is in orders, shouldn't that be `belongs_to :referral` ?

Comment: since you are creating referral based on an order, I think, `has_one :order` should come in `Referral` and `belongs_to :referral` should come in `Order`.